# Google Maps API Key Error when launching Activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to build an application that uses a Google maps activity using Android Studio.

I am facing issue: every time I try to launch the activity the app crashes. When I am using an emulator with SDK 24, the activity launches, it requires my permission and then it gives me an authentication error, even though I placed the correct API key.

On an emulator with SDK 26 the activity doesn't even launch and it crashes instantly.

Can you please help with this?

**MapsActivity**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import java.util.ArrayList;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        getLocationPermission();
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Error from the logcat for an emulator with SDK 24:**

```
    06-21 16:52:53.625 13392-13392/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
06-21 16:52:55.011 1314-1321/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-21 16:52:55.452 13392-13560/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
06-21 16:52:55.454 13392-13560/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
        API Key: XXX_Key
        Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): D3:DF:7B:C7:09:CA:00:9F:32:DD:93:98:D6:E2:09:A1:18:B1:F6:6B;com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature
06-21 16:53:01.866 13392-13392/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature, PID: 13392
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1234, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity.initMap(MapsActivity.java:110)
        at com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MapsActivity.java:154)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7067)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6919)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4049)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4096) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1516) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
06-21 16:53:02.076 1314-1322/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-21 16:53:05.957 8187-8220/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '65bcf76 com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-21 16:53:05.957 8187-8220/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '23dfb3a com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-21 16:53:26.978 8543-12462/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
06-21 16:53:27.653 8543-11730/? E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED
06-21 16:53:28.495 8906-13710/? E/FontsPackageChangeOp: Error adding manifest dependency for newly downloaded font {Press Start 2P, wdth 100.0, wght 400, ital 0.0, bestEffort false}
06-21 16:53:28.507 8906-13053/? E/FontDisk: Error inserting metadata for Press Start 2P
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metadata.db
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1442)
        at vdo.run(Unknown Source)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-21 16:53:29.228 13637-13764/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
06-21 16:53:29.611 13637-13764/? E/Finsky: [464] com.google.android.finsky.am.c.a(34): Unable to build selector: /storage/emulated/0/Download/marketenvs.csv (No such file or directory)
06-21 16:53:30.423 13637-13637/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.y.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
06-21 16:53:35.484 13637-13828/? E/Finsky: [483] com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.ad.a(3): Can't schedule deferred install. No modules found.
06-21 16:53:36.939 13637-13637/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.y.a(3): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
06-21 16:53:37.759 13836-13836/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
06-21 16:53:38.320 8906-8965/? E/AsyncOpDispatcher: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
06-21 16:53:39.373 8543-13891/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
06-21 16:53:39.503 8543-13891/? E/GCoreUlr: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing location or location status: 3016643, -1, 3781840, 7160153
        at awot.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):387)
        at awos.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):12)
        at awos.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):7)
        at oup.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):6)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-21 16:53:40.868 12038-13901/? E/art: The String#value field is not present on Android versions >= 6.0
06-21 16:58:10.742 8543-13895/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
06-21 16:58:10.743 8543-13895/? E/GCoreUlr: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing location or location status: 3016643, -1, 3781840, 7431479
        at awot.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):387)
        at awos.a(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):12)
        at awos.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):7)
        at oup.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):6)
        at ovb.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431):27)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at pbc.run(:com.google.android.gms@12685026@12.6.85 (040700-197041431))
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
06-21 17:07:17.957 8543-9125/? E/WakeLock: release without a matched acquire!
06-21 17:07:18.371 14053-14083/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mmsconfig
06-21 17:07:18.376 14053-14083/? E/Babel_SMS: canonicalizeMccMnc: invalid mccmnc nullnull
```

**Error from the logcat for an emulator with SDK 26:**

```
    06-21 17:13:05.646 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:14.440 1929-2545/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature-sqq-lfGT9yN1ITtLhodWNA==/base.apk
06-21 17:13:14.440 1929-2545/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature-sqq-lfGT9yN1ITtLhodWNA==/base.apk
06-21 17:13:14.441 1929-2545/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature-sqq-lfGT9yN1ITtLhodWNA==/base.apk
06-21 17:13:14.441 1929-2545/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature-sqq-lfGT9yN1ITtLhodWNA==/base.apk
06-21 17:13:14.443 1929-2545/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature-sqq-lfGT9yN1ITtLhodWNA==/base.apk
06-21 17:13:14.899 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:15.787 5360-5360/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature, PID: 5360
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity.initMap(MapsActivity.java:110)
        at com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity.getLocationPermission(MapsActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
06-21 17:13:16.975 1510-1510/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-21 17:13:16.976 1510-1510/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-21 17:13:16.978 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-21 17:13:16.990 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-21 17:13:16.990 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-21 17:13:16.998 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-21 17:13:17.682 2308-2853/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7
06-21 17:13:17.794 2308-2308/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
06-21 17:13:17.895 2308-2308/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
06-21 17:13:22.074 1510-1650/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-21 17:13:22.074 1510-1650/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-21 17:13:22.074 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-21 17:13:22.084 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-21 17:13:22.084 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-21 17:13:22.086 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
06-21 17:13:27.115 1510-1648/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-21 17:13:27.116 1510-1648/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-21 17:13:27.116 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-21 17:13:27.123 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-21 17:13:27.124 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
06-21 17:13:27.714 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:27.737 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:31.070 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:31.084 1744-1775/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
06-21 17:13:32.154 1510-1650/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
06-21 17:13:32.155 1510-1650/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
06-21 17:13:32.155 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
06-21 17:13:32.157 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
06-21 17:13:32.157 2349-5365/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

**Msps Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':base')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.orhanobut:logger:1.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"

}
```

Comment: Also share the code of layout file.

Comment: You have exposed your map key...quickly remove that..regenerate that for security

Comment: No worries, it was not the current one.

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055893/ensure-that-the-google-maps-android-api-v2-is-enabled-i-am-getting-this-error

Comment: Have you enabled "Google Maps Android API v2" in google developers console ?

Comment: Is your "Msps Activity Layout" in `activity_maps.xml` file?

Comment: I've already tried everything from that post. It didn't helped.

Comment: Yes, my Maps Activity Layout is in activity_maps.xml and I had enabled "Google Maps Android API v2".

Comment: The error is in this `mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);` line, because `mapFragment == null`,  so `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)` didn't find `SupportMapFragment` with `R.id.map` id... So double check that `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);` set correct layout (with `android:id="@+id/map"` fragment that has `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` class)

Comment: Try to create new project with only one `Activity`  with `SupportMapFragment` (or even get rid of `SupportMapFragment` and use `MapFragment`) to detect issue. Than compare xml/gradle files with your product project to find differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your map in onCreate() as done here and this will do your job.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback
{

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Mapready", "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted)
        {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //vars
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        initMap();

        getLocationPermission();
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){

                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    DEFAULT_ZOOM);

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude );
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, do the following changes in the manifest file:-

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
 android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

Comment: Now it crashes immediately when i try to launch the activity with this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature/com.example.raluca.geoloc.feature.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Please try to execute the app in android Marshmallow device

Comment: Send the gradle file. I want to see the dependencies used.

Comment: I have added the Gradle

Comment: Run the app with latest dependencies:-
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

Comment: Still the same error. It doesn't like the fragment part.

Answer (score 0):

Create a New Project and check on the  "Use androidx.* artifacts" and it will work fine.
Should use API 23 or newer.