# Do i need multiple API keys for Google maps?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api, api-key

I am working on an app with a group of friends for class and we are utilizing the Google Maps API. My friend setup the map for the app and has it working on his machine and his testing tablet, but when using the application on my end I receive an error about my API key being incorrect and I get a beige box and a Google logo.

We have transferred the debug.keystore file between our machines and I am receiving the same LogCat errors as before, see below. Is it necessary to have another key for my machine, and then a third for the last member of our group?

````
2019-04-29 19:06:07.556 21706-21861/com.example.changejar E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
2019-04-29 19:06:07.561 21706-21861/com.example.changejar E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
```
````

Comment: There may be problem with Api Key Restrictions, Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464293/8432542

Comment: yes you can add multiple SHA1 key for your google map key.