# Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure. Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that the following Android Key exists

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-android-api-1

I am getting this error:

```
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: [The key...]
    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>):
```

Instead of the map working correctly, this is what I see:

[image]

In my `app/build.gradle`, I have this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

`play-services-location` is what I need for the Google Maps, correct? I was looking at the list at https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup and I assume that `Google Location and Activity Recognition - com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0` is what I need for Google Maps. Is this correct?

**UPDATE 1:** I already have Maps SDK for Android enabled:

[image]

The error says: `Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.`. Is it referring to the `Maps SDK for Android` that I am showing in the screenshot in this **UPDATE 1**?

**UPDATE 2:** I have `Maps SDK for Android` enabled:

[image]

When I click the `MANAGE` button, I can go to the section to configure credentials that I showed in **UPDATE 1**.

**UPDATE 3:** I see the Map displayed correctly on all versions of Android on the Emulator. But on physical devices, the map never shows up. I see the Google logo and the red balloon, but now the map when I run the app on physical phones. Only on the Emulator everything works. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE 4:** See my solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307654/4242086.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this tutorial and I was able to fix it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJBlQv6IptQ. The video makes references to this tutorial: http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-maps-android-example-in-android.html.

In my case, what I did was to create a new project at https://console.developers.google.com/. I used `Android apps` for `Application restrictions`:

[image]

For the `Restrict usage to your Android apps` section, I had to provide a `Package name` and a `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint`. The `Package name` was in my `app/build.gradle`, specifically here:

```
applicationId "[my package name]"
```

The `SHA-1 certificate fingerprint` I found it from Android Studio by running `signingReport`:

[image]

The result included something like this:

```
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: [The value]
SHA1: [The value]
SHA-256: [The value]
Valid until: Wednesday, May 5, 2049
----------

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
16:31:44: Task execution finished 'signingReport'.
```

Now the map works correctly in my Android app:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:** To my surprise, the maps were working correctly only on the Android Studio Emulator but not on real Android physical devices. The solution was what I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56307654/4242086.

Comment: Updating applicationId was the key to solve my problem for me, thank you so much

Comment: I select NONE for testing

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had the same problem today!,I solved it very easy for first you have to go  https://console.developers.google.com and enable the android SDK maps and then create the api key, return in xamarin go to your manifest and add the google maps api key

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows

This is the documentation 
(I typed this fast because am on mobile now sorry)

Comment: See my update 1. I already have `Maps SDK for Android` enabled.

Comment: Have you added your api key to your androidmanifest? If yes try to uncheck the api restrictions

Comment: I created a new API key and added it to my `AndroidManifest.xml`. It already works for me, as you can see in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: oh good am very happy now it works! (can you mark my answer as correct? need that badge)

Comment: I voted up for your answer and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

follow to below link for generate google api key:-
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker

Android Code Reference Link:-

https://www.zoftino.com/android-mapview-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same symptoms when I moved the project to a new computer. My solution was to generate a new key based on the error message. The google_maps_api.xml file had an URL in a comment to generate key but that is a static thing, so after moving the project to a new computer I rewrote the URL to match the error message's version.

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=[put-the-thing-here]

Generated the key, put it in the XML file and it worked well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did everything right. but was still getting the error it turned out that changing the attribute "android:name" in the manifest file solved the issue.

Change

```
android:name="com.google.android.maps.API_KEY"
```

To

```
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
```

Answer (score 1):

Time changed the configurations steps. Here the new one.

1. Set up your project https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/home/dashboard
2. Enable Google Maps API. Go to  https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?filter=category:maps&_ga=2.192684329.2027491681.1618180744-3962552.1609436892 choose the API you want to enable
3. Go to API Credentials https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential of your project
4. On the Credentials page, click Create credentials > API key.
   The API key created dialog displays your newly created API key
5. Click Close.
6. In Android Studio, open your app-level build.gradle file and add the following code to the plugins element. `id 'com.google.secrets_gradle_plugin' version '0.5'`
7. Save the file and sync your project with Gradle
8. Open `values\google_maps_api.xml` and replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with the API got in the point 4.
9. Check in your AndroidManifest.xml the `MAPS_API_KEY` is replaced with your actual key

```
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAPS_API_KEY}" />
```

10. Insert in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

11. Go to the APIs & Services > Credentials page https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/apiui/credential
12. Select the API key that you want to set a restriction on. The API key property page appears
13. Under Key restrictions --> Select Android apps.
    Click + Add package name and fingerprint.
    Enter your package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprintClick Restrict key.
    Select Maps SDK for Android from Select APIs dropdow
14. To finalize your changes, click Save.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still haven't figured it out yet, again take a look at the logging below the error message. Pay close attention to your **certifcate_fingerprint** and **package_name** printed out in the logging. Compare these diligently with the ones specified in your Google Development Console.

I picked up an old hobby project again after almost an entire year of inactivity. I probably changed something somewhere that triggered a change of the certificate fingerprint, or visa versa.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Generating a new API KEY, and adding your Project's FINGERPRINT and PACKAGE NAME, in the ANDROID RESTRICTION Section, as shown below helped me with the problem,

[image]

Do remember to add the new API KEY to your Project's Android Manifest file