# Google Api Authentication failed while setting google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I was using google map API in my app was working fine  but yesterday when I added some other feature in the app and started testing it suddenly Map API is no longer working so I thought there may be some issue with the code so I checked and found that I have not changed anything in the map API but when I try to create another app in the Google API came to know that limit is crossed and not even able to see what are the current project I have as the limit is 30 as it says but, in reality, I have used mostly 4-6 app using the API . I looked into other similar questions and tried the same thing but no solution so far. Any solution that may help me will be helpful
I am  getting this error while running

```
Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
```

the key is there and As i said it was the same app which was working earlier.

Comment: Did you restricted the key in google developer console?

Comment: I open the console yesterday itself earlier not done anything

Answer (score 0):

Following steps might help:-
1. Login to google devloper console.
2. Select your project
3. Select "Library". 
4. Check Maps API if it is enabled or not.

Comment: I tried what you are saying thats why i put the question heading as google Api authentication failed

Comment: Did you checked the keystore, is it same as earlier? Is this application live on play store?

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: - 1.You might have restricted the key on console. 2. You have not enabled the map API.

Comment: As i said the api was working till yesterday and suddenly not showing at all

Comment: If api library is not showing anything that means Maps API is not enabled. You have to enable it. Make sure you are using correct account for this.

Comment: let me try few more time i will let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201655/discussion-between-prashant-sable-and-neelay-srivastava).

Answer (score 0):

```
1 => https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2 => create credentials
3 => Api key 
4 => Restrick Key
5 => Application restrictions -> Android apps and API restrictions -> Don't restrict key
6 => Save then wait for 5 min then use generated api key
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055893/ensure-that-the-google-maps-android-api-v2-is-enabled-i-am-getting-this-error

Comment: it is saying nothing found